# Sum of polynomials inequality

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

I've encountered a paper that given $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_m \in \mathbb N_+$ and $k \in \mathbb N_+, k \le m$ assumes that the following inequality holds without further comment:

$\hspace{20pt}\mathcal O\left(\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{m - k + 1} \left(a_i + a_{i + 1} + \ldots + a_{i + k - 1}\right)^{2k - 1}\right) \le \mathcal O\left(\left(a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_m\right)^{2k - 1}\right)$

I can't seem to come up with a proof.

Edit: Added [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: I believe you merely have to show that the left half of the inequality is a subset of the right half. By inspection, the right half appears to contain all of the left half plus zero to m-k+1 additional elements.

Comment: @poetasis What do you mean by elements?

Comment: Think of the left and right as being sets. By elements, I mean members of those sets. Sorry for the sloppy 'language'. I could also be way off base. It was just my impression by glancing at the problem.

Comment: How exactly are those sets defined?

Comment: What is between the parentheses is not exactly a set but a sum of elements so there is no set definition per se but they can be thought of that way as member_1 + member_2+....  I'm just suggesting that the right parentheses may begin with the same member-sums as the left but then it has 0_to_m-(k+1) additional members. For formal language, I recommend "Book of Proof" by Richard H. Hammack.

Comment: The guy with the answer below may or may not be correct depending on how you interpret the summation: Does it apply to the left side only or to both sides of the inequality. Then there is still some question if the right side can have an arbitrarily greater number of members than the left.